# combine multiple json output queries

Tags: json, postgresql

Query 1:

```
UPDATE liaison
SET content = replace( replace( content::varchar, content->>'important_maintenance_problem_id', '{' || (content->>'important_maintenance_problem_id') || '}' ), 'important_maintenance_problem_id', 'important_maintenance_problem_ids' )::JSON
WHERE
content ? 'important_maintenance_problem_id';
```

Query 2:

```
UPDATE liaison
SET content = replace( replace( content::varchar, content->>'urgent_maintenance_problem_id', '{' || (content->>'urgent_maintenance_problem_id') || '}' ), 'urgent_maintenance_problem_id', 'urgent_maintenance_problem_ids' )::JSON
WHERE
content ? 'urgent_maintenance_problem_id';
```

In this both queries I updated json data for important_maintenance_problem_id to important_maintenace_problem_ids AND urgent_maintenance_problem_id to urgent_maintenance_problem_ids respectively. Is there any way we can combine both this query? I tried but since we are using same content hence failed to combine.

Answer (score 0):

Because both update queries use the same table they can be combined into one query with a `CASE END` clause.

```
UPDATE
 liaison

SET content = (
        CASE
          WHEN content ? 'important_maintenance_problem_id'
          THEN replace( replace( content::varchar, content->>'important_maintenance_problem_id', '{' || (content->>'important_maintenance_problem_id') || '}' ), 'important_maintenance_problem_id', 'important_maintenance_problem_ids' )::JSON

           WHEN content ? 'urgent_maintenance_problem_id'
           THEN replace( replace( content::varchar, content->>'urgent_maintenance_problem_id', '{' || (content->>'urgent_maintenance_problem_id') || '}' ), 'urgent_maintenance_problem_id', 'urgent_maintenance_problem_ids' )::JSON

            ELSE 
              content 
        END
      )

WHERE
   content ? 'important_maintenance_problem_id'
 OR
   content ? 'urgent_maintenance_problem_id'
```